# Prove $\sum_{r=0}^n 6r=3n(n+1)$ using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Prove$$\sum_{r=0}^n 6r=3n(n+1)$$using Induction

I'm a little confused as to how I would calculate the latter

Comment: Could you please rewrite this in proper Latex format?

Comment: Of course, if you already know that $\sum_{i=0}^{k} i = k(k+1)/2$, then it follows immediately that $\sum_{i=0}^{k}6i = 6\sum_{i=0}^{k} i = 6k(k+1)/2 = 3k(k+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that it's true For $n=k$

$$\sum_{r=0}^k 6r=3k(k+1)$$

Then show that it's also true for n=(k+1)

$$\sum_{r=0}^{k+1} 6r=6(k+1)+\sum_{r=0}^{k} 6r=6(k+1)+3k(k+1)=3k^2+9k+6=3(k+1)(k+2)$$